# Flex 4 fails to parse XML with quoted text

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flex4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WorkItems>
  <WorkItem Duration="1" ID="1" Title="this breaks: &quot;"></WorkItem>
</WorkItems>
```

I embed this XML into my Flex 4 app:

```
<fx:XML source="data.xml" id="Data">
</fx:XML>
```

And I get an error: `TypeError: Error #1090: XML parser failure: element is malformed.`

If I remove the quot part of the title it works fine. How come? Isn't this the proper way to escape "?

---

**Edit**: Opened a [bug with Adobe](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-28103).

Answer (score 1):

That's valid XML, possibly a bug in Flex...? Try parsing it in ActionScript instead and see what happens.

Comment: if I turn the title into a sub element it works also.. I guess it's a bug handling quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

```
You could look into using <![CDATA[ ]]> , maybe that will help your efforts.
```

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=224590"Naam"]]>BlockquoteBlockquote

Comment: Sorry I was not paying attention that you have quote in the XML atribute. &quot; should work for Flash Player.   If it does not for Flex , then it is a bug of mxmlc compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue - though I was working with free standing "&" characters and had to do preprocess the XML with:

```
        $xml = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $response->getBody());
```

Can you pre-process the XML to change the escape string into character literals?